# Properly handling an exception

Tags: c++, error-handling, try-catch, throw

My understanding is that in modern C++, it is preferable to use `throw` instead of returning an error code.  That is to say, if I have some function:

```
void MyFunction(int foo, double bar){
    // Do some stuff....

    if (exception_criteria_met){
        throw "Call to MyFunction with inputs" << foo << " and " << bar << " failed because ...";
    }
};
```

Does this mean that, in order to properly handle this, then in all functions that make a call to `MyFunction`, I must implement something like:

```
void MyOuterFunction(int foo){
    // Do some stuff...

    try {
        MyFunction(foo, bar);
    } catch (const char * exception_message) {
        throw "Call to MyOuterFunction with inputs " << foo << " failed because call to MyFunction with ....";
    };
```

And then wouldn't that imply that I must perform this same kind of error handling *all the way down* through all functions that calls into this stack of function calls?  Obviously at some point, maybe one of the functions can actually handle the exception and not need to throw an exception of its own, but perhaps just print a warning or something similar.  But how do you keep this organized and intelligible?  It seems like a remarkably complicated thing to think all the way through when you've got many functions interacting with one another.

(As a secondary question, if `MyFunction(foo,bar)` were to return a value that I wanted to use, wouldn't it mean that after leaving the `try { }` block, the returned value would fall out of scope?  Does that imply I should avoid using function return values if I'm going to be using `try-catch`?)

Comment: `My understanding is that in modern C++, it is preferable to use throw instead of returning an error code.` Not quite. Seems like we're sailing back to favoring returning errors rather than throwing, see for example [`std::expected`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/expected)

Comment: you should catch an exception when it makes sense to catch it, eg when you can recover from it in a meaningful way. Then you recover from it and the code all the way up the call stack do not even notice that there was an exception. Catching and rethrowing is rarely useful.

Comment: You cat let exceptions unwind the stack till a function catch it and handle it. it's not required to catch the exception immediately at caller code. you can do it in caller of caller. Also the benefits and downsides of exceptions is arguable. same about the right place of using them.

Comment: if you have to catch an exception from a function in the calling function, then you might as well be using error return codes. The whole point is that exceptions do not have to be caught immediately.

Comment: You cannot generally say that throwing exceptions is better than returning an error code. It is like saying that a hammer is better than a screwdriver. It might be, but it depends on the problem at hand.

Comment: If you are not on C++23 for `std::expected`, there is Boost [`outcome` & `result`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/outcome/doc/html/tutorial/essential.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think most of your question is either too broad or opinion based or both. However, your confusion seems to start with

> then in all functions that make a call to MyFunction, I must implement something like:

That's not right.

The function calling `MyFunction` that potentially throws can look like this:

```
void MyOuterFunction(int foo){
    // Do some stuff...
    MyFunction(foo, bar);
};
```

If you would have to always catch an exception immediately, exceptions would be rather impractical. Thats not how they work.

In a nutshell: The exception continues to travel up the call stack until you either catch it or `main` is reached and it is still not caught, in that case the program terminates.

There is no fixed rule where you should catch the exception. My personal rule of thumb is to catch it when it is possible to recover from it, but not sooner. Sometimes not catching an expection at all is the most viable. Catching and rethrowing is rarely useful and catching it only to rethrow as you do is never useful to my knowledge.

Comment: On the other hand, catch and throw as something else can be very useful when crossing a library boundary.